# .NET SDK Not installing for VS Code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I wanted to code unity with my VS Code. I searched and found that I need .NET SDK.
I downloaded the exe from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download.
It runs for 5-6 hours saying "Add .NET SDK to the path".

I cancelled the process many times but the same happens everytime

What should I do?
TYSM In advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dotnet folder to your environment variables. Well, that's according to that quote you included.

```
   - Start the System Control Panel applet (Start - Settings - Control Panel - System).
   - Select the Advanced tab.
   - Click the Environment Variables button.
   - Under System Variables, select Path, then click Edit.
   - Add C:\Program Files\dotnet to path.
   - Save and close all CMD windows
   - Should work now
```